# How to use kfold to train model in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I expected the `kfold` object to have a `fit` function attached to just like `GridSearchCV`:

```
spipe = Pipeline([
    ('scale', StandardScaler()),
    ('model', somemodel())
])

grid = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=pipe,
    cv=4
)

grid.fit(X, Y)
```

But `kfold` doesn't have the `fit` method and in the [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#k-fold) they don't really show how to use it, instead I think they imply that it should be used with `cross_val_score`?

The problem is that `cross_val_score` fits the data on each fold separately; what I want  is to use all folds to make 1 fit to train the model.

Is that possible or I'm not understanding the purpose of the folds.

Comment: What `kfold` object are you referring to? It's not defined here

Comment: kfold is not a model to have a training method. It's there only to define which portion of the data is for training and which for validation

Comment: @TinoD ok. So how do I train a model first on 9 folds, then on the other nine folds and so on iteratively and get 1 fit from all ten iterations?

Comment: @JeniaIvanov You may improve the question with suggestions presented here.

Answer (score 0):

Packages needed for the approach:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
```

Define a model of your choice, let's call it `mdl`. That I will leave for you to choose.

Then, define your k-fold, in the comments, you wanted 9:

```
myKFold = KFold(n_splits=9, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
```

To get the scores, you need your `predictors` and a `response`, as well as the model `mdl` and naturally, `myKFold`:

```
scores = cross_val_score(model, predictors, response, cv=myKFold)
```

You can then display the `scores` of each iteration, as well as an average and the associated deviation by using `scores.mean()` and `scores.std()`, respectively.

Now, I have a feeling that some basics need to be mentioned. When using k-fold cross validation, you are training k models, each time with a different mix of training data and validation data. So to answer your last question:

> get 1 fit from all ten iterations?

That, I am afraid, *is not really possible*, unless there is some way that I do not know. However, this leaves you with some options:

- Using ensemble learning, where the predictions are done by all `k` models and then you train the weights of each model
- An "aggregate" of the `k` models would also be to train one model on
  all the dataset.

Comment: I think the true answer is that kfold is used for verifying your model not for fitting it. That's how kfold should be used. So to say it in other words, the purpose of folding is to use a new fold for verifying against the same (almost) 9 input folds.

Comment: The 9 input and test folds are not the same. That's the whole point, that you are testing how robust your model can be when trained on different sections of the dataset. So generally did you understand my answer? or is there still something unclear?